# What is the correct markup to add more information to a radio or label?

Tags: html, accessibility

I have a set of radio buttons in the format below. I'm using a legend and a fieldset to group the radio buttons and give the set a label. I'm styling the input to be hidden, and then styling the label to look more like a button.

My Question:
If I want to add more context for one of the buttons, what is the most accessibility friendly way of doing that? I was thinking about adding a title attribute to the label of "Vote '?' if you wish to abstain". I don't mind this appearing in a tooltip, so `title` seems work fine, I'm just not sure how it is handled by screen readers.

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Votes</legend>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" class="hidden" value="0" /> ?
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" class="hidden" value="1" /> 1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" class="hidden" value="2" /> 2
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" class="hidden" value="3" /> 3
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"add more context for one of the buttons"_? do you simply want more information next to the buttons?

Comment: The button that is a question mark, could have some extra text like "select this option if you feel this topic needs discussion"

Answer (score 1):

You can Edit Like below:

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Votes</legend>
  <label title="0">
    <input name="r1" type="radio" class="hidden" value="0" /> ?
  </label>
  <label title="1">
    <input name="r1" type="radio" class="hidden" value="1" /> 1
  </label>
  <label title="2">
    <input name="r1" type="radio" class="hidden" value="2" /> 2
  </label>
  <label title="3">
    <input name="r1" type="radio" class="hidden" value="3" /> 3
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following a common practice, similar to how bootstrap uses its screen reader-only helper (.sr-only), you could use CSS to offset the text within the label so that it is hidden to the visual user and only visible to the screen reader.

Using the title attribute on the label you will be relying on the specific user's AT usage of the label title attribute.

```
<label for="ir1">
    <input id="ir1" name="r1" type="radio" class="hidden" value="0" /> 
    visual text
    <span class="sr-only">additional screen reader only text</span>
</label>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes-screen-readers

```
.sr-only {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some screen reader + browser combinations don't honor "implicit" labels (input fields nested in a label) because they don't associate the label with their respective (nested) input element.  That's a bug on their end but is something you should try to avoid.  So the first thing I would do is add the `for` attribute to all the <label> elements.

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Votes</legend>
  <label for="r1">
    <input name="myradio" id="r1" type="radio" class="hidden" value="0" /> ?
  </label>
  <label for="r2">
    <input name="myradio" id="r2" type="radio" class="hidden" value="1" /> 1
  </label>
  <label for="r3">
    <input name="myradio" id="r3" type="radio" class="hidden" value="2" /> 2
  </label>
  <label for="r4">
    <input name="myradio" id="r4" type="radio" class="hidden" value="3" /> 3
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

**Note**, your original code did not have a `name` attribute for each <input> so the radio buttons were not programatically grouped together.  I added `name="myradio"` to each one.  I also added an ID to each <input> and now each <label> points to each <input> via its `for` attribute.

One possible way to add additional text to each label is to use visually hidden text that is still available to screen readers.  @jcruz mentioned that and it's one possibility.  It's a pretty common technique.

Another solution, and possibly a little simpler than hidden text, is to have an [`aria-label`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-label) attribute on each <input>.  The `aria-label` is not visible.  It's there solely for the screen reader.  The `aria-label` will **override** anything in the <label>.  But one caution when having both visible text and an `aria-label`, the `aria-label` must contain the same text as in the visual label, plus it can have additional text.  This is a new WCAG 2.1 guideline and is called "[2.5.3 Label in Name](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/label-in-name.html)".  So you can visually have "2" as the <label> but the `aria-label` could be "*vote two times to get your candidate in office*".  In this case, whether you have "two" or "2" in the label doesn't matter.  A speech interface user can say "click two" and the correct radio button will be selected.

(Note that with a braille device, there is a difference.  One would show the word "two" and the other would show the number "2", but again, in this case it might not matter.)

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Votes</legend>
  <label for="r1">
    <input name="myradio" id="r1" type="radio" aria-label="Not sure who to vote for?  Abstain" class="hidden" value="0" /> ?
  </label>
  <label for="r2">
    <input name="myradio" id="r2" type="radio" aria-label="Vote one time to be honest" class="hidden" value="1" /> 1
  </label>
  <label for="r3">
    <input name="myradio" id="r3" type="radio" aria-label="Vote two times to get your candidate in office" class="hidden" value="2" /> 2
  </label>
  <label for="r4">
    <input name="myradio" id="r4" type="radio" aria-label="Vote three times if you're really passionate" class="hidden" value="3" /> 3
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

**Note** that you might have a special case that I didn't test with speech recognition software.  As mentioned, the `aria-label` needs to contain the visible text from the label.  With your first radio, it's a question mark.  I'm not sure if speech recognition will expect "click question mark", and if the "?" in the aria-label will match.